# integration of sinc related function

Tags: integration

Here is a question about the integration of a function related to $\operatorname{sinc}$.

$$\int_{-B}^{B}\bigg(\frac{\sin(Df\pi)}{D\sin(f\pi)}\bigg)^Ldf$$

Where $B, D, L$ are known positive integers, how can one calculate this integral?

The background of this issue is that the Guassian white noise with zero mean is filtered by the average filter for $L$ times, and the mean power of the filtered noise is wanted.

Thank you.

Comment: How is $f$ related to other constants?

Comment: @Szeto, actually, the equation means the integration of the filtered AGWN(white noise) in the bandwidth from $-B$ to $B$, and $B$ is determined by sampling frequency.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I have added the background of the problem,  hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Trying (using a CAS) for small values of integer $L$, the antiderivative can be found. They are monsters invloving a bunch of hypergeometric functions.

To give you a flavor, for $L=1$, the antiderivative would be
$$\frac{i e^{-i \pi  (D-1) f} \left((D+1)\, \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1-D}{2};\frac{3-D}{2};e^{2 i f \pi
   }\right)+(D-1)\, e^{2 i \pi  D f} \,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1+D}{2};\frac{3+D}{2};e^{2 i f
   \pi }\right)\right)}{\pi  (D-1) D (D+1)}$$

I shall not write any other.